# GUI - Display lines one by one on a JTextPane and make a related JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, progress-bar, jtextpane

How to display lines one by one on a `JTextPane` and make a related `JProgressBar`?

I have this loop:

```
  int k;
  for (k=0; k<array_TXT.length; k++) {
    if (array_TXT[k] != null) { 
      textPane.append( array_TXT[k] );
    }
 }
```

I'd like to append every line `array_TXT[k]` (string) on the `JTextPane` one by one after few seconds and it has to be synchronized to a `JProgressBar`.

In this way every time `k` has a different value it will print on the text pane and the progress bar will always be related to those prints.

I have read about `Thread.sleep(x);` but I don't know where to put it in order to reach my aim.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You should add the SwingTimer as a answer so I can up vote it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Entered as answer..

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). It will allow you to execute the updates in the background, off the Event Dispatching Thread.

The SwingWorker has methods to allow you to `publish` and `process` updates back to the Event Dispatching Thread.

It also allows you to fire and monitor progress updates

### SwingWorker Example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ProgressMonitor;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProgress();
    }

    public TestProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
                JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.add(pb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                new BackgroundWorker(ta, pb).execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        private JProgressBar pb;
        private JTextArea ta;

        public BackgroundWorker(JTextArea ta, JProgressBar pb) {
            this.pb = pb;
            this.ta = ta;
            addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        BackgroundWorker.this.pb.setValue(getProgress());
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String text : chunks) {
                ta.append(text);
                ta.append("\n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                publish("Line " + index);
                setProgress(index);
                Thread.sleep(125);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

### Swing Timer Example

As suggest by Andrew, the following is an example of using a `SwingTimer`.  If you find it useful, please give Andrew credit for the idea

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProgress();
    }

    private int index = 0;

    public TestProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
                final JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.add(pb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        index++;
                        if (index >= 100) {
                            ((Timer)(e.getSource())).stop();
                        }
                        ta.append("Line " + index + "\n");
                        pb.setValue(index);
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks, could you please give a little example about how to do that loop, considering that I'm working on a 'textpane1' and I use '.append' to append strings to that textpane1 and I use a 'progressbar1' ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.